# Jquery, Ajax and JSON parsing undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Can anyone tell me why I cannot get field.set_url to come up?

http://jsfiddle.net/W4xBJ/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards?color=red&color=blue&rarity=rare&name=fire",function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("div").append(field.name + "<br>" + field.url + "<br> "+ field.id + "<br> "+ field.set_url + "<br>");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What happens if you print out the first index of `editions`... `field.editions[0].set_url` ?

Comment: I think you may have answered this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set_url` doesn't appear to be there in the result object, at least not for the first result:

```
{
  "editions": [
    {
      "store_url": "http://store.tcgplayer.com/magic/odyssey/ashen-firebeast?partner=DECKBREW",
      "set_url": "https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/sets/ODY",
      "image_url": "https://image.deckbrew.com/mtg/multiverseid/29965.jpg",
      "url": "https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards?multiverseid=29965",
      "price": {
        "note": "store.tcgplayer.com allows you to buy cards from any of our vendors, all at the same time, in a simple checkout experience. Shop, Compare & Save with TCGplayer.com!",
        "high": 103,
        "median": 32,
        "low": 14
      },
      "set": "Odyssey",
      "set_id": "ODY",
      "rarity": "rare",
      "artist": "Mark Tedin",
      "multiverse_id": 29965,
      "flavor": "\"I'm not sure which impresses me most, its thoroughness or its intensity.\"\n\n—Matoc, lavamancer",
      "number": "174",
      "layout": "normal"
    }
  ],
  "formats": {
    "vintage": "legal",
    "legacy": "legal",
    "commander": "legal"
  },
  "toughness": "6",
  "power": "6",
  "text": "{1}{R}: Ashen Firebeast deals 1 damage to each creature without flying.",
  "cost": "{6}{R}{R}",
  "name": "Ashen Firebeast",
  "id": "ashen-firebeast",
  "url": "https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards/ashen-firebeast",
  "store_url": "http://store.tcgplayer.com/magic/odyssey/ashen-firebeast?partner=DECKBREW",
  "types": [
    "creature"
  ],
  "subtypes": [
    "beast",
    "elemental"
  ],
  "colors": [
    "red"
  ],
  "cmc": 8
}
```

Perhaps you meant `store_url`, or maybe `set_url` from the object(s) in the array of `editions`?

**UPDATE**:

To use the `set_url` within the `editions` array, just iterate over it as before:

Inside the first `$.each`, put this:

```
$.each(field.editions, function (index, edition) {
  // do something with edition.set_url
});
```

Comment: Yes, how would I now add the array that lies within editions?

Comment: ^ I updated my answer with the code for accessing `set_url` from `editions`.

Comment: also, function(I, field).... what does the "i" reference or what is its function?

Comment: In the `each` method, the first argument is the index of the iteration, starting from 0.

Comment: Btw, if an answer solves your problem, you should mark it as correct  :)

Answer (score 0):

I have update the jsfiddle try this

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/W4xBJ/2/][1]
```

Actually your key is store_url not set_url. you were using the wrong key